# Able to make migration with associations but not able to query with associations (association not found)

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've built a database with a couple tables that are associated with each other: Auction and Bids. Each Auction should have many Bids and each Bid should have only one Auction. I made a migration fine to add foreignKeys but when I try to look up a certain Bid on an Auction I receive a `SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Bids is not associated to Auctions!` error.

migrations file:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.addColumn(
      'Auctions', // name of target model
      'BidId',
      {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references:{
          model: "bids",
          key: "bid_id",
        },
      },
    );
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Auction');
  }
};
```

bids.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');


// const resolver = require('graphql-sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/database');
const Auction = require('./Auction');

const tableName = 'bids';
const Bids = sequelize.define('Bids', {
  bid_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  createdAt: {
   type: Sequelize.DATE,
   // defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
  },
  amount: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  bid_amount: {
    type:Sequelize.STRING
  },
  bid_no: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
  },
}, 
{tableName})

Bids.associate = () => {
  Bids.hasOne(Auction, {foreignKey:"BidId"})
};
```

auction.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/database');
const tableName = 'Auctions';
const Auction = sequelize.define('Auctions', {
  auc_id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4, // generate the UUID automatically
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  features: {
    type: Sequelize.JSONB,
  },
  bid_amount: {
    type:Sequelize.STRING
  },
  BidId: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
  }
}, { tableName });

Auction.hasMany(Bids, {foreignKey: 'BidId'}) 

module.exports = Auction
```

query.js

```
const findBidOnAuction = () => {Auction.findOne({where:{BidId:2}, include:[{model:Bids}]}).then(data => console.log("result", data))}
```

How do I properly associate these tables?

edit: Also on pgAdmin I can that the relationship exists, BidId is a foreignKey on Auction linked to bid_id on Bids

Answer (score 1):

I do the following for add a foreignKey on migrations:

1.I create a migration for the parent model with a `ref` function.
    const TABLE_NAME = 'parent';

```
function up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
  return queryInterface.createTable(
    TABLE_NAME, //Bid model
    {
      //attributes
    },
  );
}

function down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
  return queryInterface.dropTable(TABLE_NAME);
}

function ref(Sequelize) {
  return {type: Sequelize.STRING(2), references: {model: TABLE_NAME, key: 'id'}}; // 'id' here is your parent (Bids) primary key
}

module.exports = {up, down, ref};
```

2.On the child model where you are going to add the reference, you import the `ref` function and added like this, so your migration actually knows which model are you refering:

```
const {ref: REF_Model} = require('name-of-your-migration-file'); //import model


  async function up(queryInterface, Sequelize){
    await queryInterface.addColumn('Auctions', 'BidId', {...REF_Model(Sequelize), allowNull: true});
  }

  async function down(queryInterface){
    await queryInterface.removeColumn('Auctions', 'BidId');
  }

module.exports = {up, down};
```

Comment: So what you're saying is that during the migrations you think the model isn't actually being referenced? In pgAdmin I can see that the association is there. But sequelize won't recognize it

Comment: I do that cause not always the reference is create it the right way. Also remember to update your actual model on sequelize (not the migration). This is just creating the column and Dr association on the db.

Comment: Okay im about to try this, just a quick question: where exactly are you making the reference on the child model? Usually there will be a `references` argument you can pass but I dont see you using that

Comment: On your child migration, the actual one that is creating the colunm, there is an import for the parent model `REF_MODEL`. So if you check the `ref()` function I return an object where there is all the setup.

Comment: doesnt work, im not seeing any FK constraints on pgadmin.

Comment: sorry not sure what im doing wrong. both of those pieces of code are seperate migration files yes? And I need to one the first then the second or?

Comment: Yeah, is a seperate migration, and I has to be before of your fk migration.